# ubuntu/ath10k: regdomain has no effect

Tags: linux, wifi, hostapd, access-point

Summary: PCEngines APU2 board with 2 identical Compex WLE600VX wireless cards. Ubuntu 22.04 with 5.19 (hwe) kernel.

I'm trying to make them work as an access points using `hostapd`, usual way.

Both cards come with US (0x0) regdomain in EEPROM, so it should work fine (in `world` regdomain all channels are marked as `No-IR` -> no AP for ya):

```
# dmesg | grep regdomain
[   22.933786] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x0
[   23.093868] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x0
```

Problem is I can't set the regdomain for the 1st card:

```
# iw reg get
global
country 98: DFS-UNSET
        (902 - 904 @ 2), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (904 - 920 @ 2), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (920 - 928 @ 2), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (2457 - 2472 @ 15), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

phy#1
country US: DFS-FCC
        (902 - 904 @ 2), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (904 - 920 @ 16), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (920 - 928 @ 8), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
        (5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW
        (5850 - 5895 @ 40), (N/A, 27), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5925 - 7125 @ 320), (N/A, 12), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0
country 99: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5140 - 5360 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5715 - 5860 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
```

`phy0` always stays `99` even after doing `iw reg set US`. Consequently I cannot use any 5Ghz frequencies on it in AP mode.

Any idea what I miss? The cards are the same, regdomain same, why they are treated differently?
I can even swap them in PCI-E slots but the result stays the same.

P.S.
If I add option `ieee80211_regdom=US` to module `cfg80211` the regdomain is shown as `US` in `iw reg get`, but the frequencies are anyway blocked in `iw list` (marked as `No-IR`):

```
                Frequencies:
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (30.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
                        * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5845 MHz [169] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
```